# Display a UIViewController after UIImagePickerController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

I know this is a hot question for iPhone programming but I can't find a good answer yet.

I've an `UITabBarController` based application with the middle `tabBarItem` overlayed by a custom button. This custom button is used for posting a new item. Like [this](http://idevrecipes.files.wordpress.com/2010/12/instagram.png?w=460&h=84) (I take Instagram, for example).

Of course this button must be accessible in the whole application.
When you click on this button you'll can see an UIImagePickerController for choosing an image from your library or from the camera.

The problem is how to display another `UIViewController` after you've chosen the image.

The first method is set a boolean variable from the `UIImagePickerController` delegate method and override the `viewDidAppear` method of **all** view controllers for checking the boolean var and if it's `TRUE`, call `[self.tabBarController presentModalViewController:MyController animated:YES]`. But I think this one is pretty ugly.

Have you others (elegant) method?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` object, trap user actions, and either present a modal view controller or send a message to a view controller to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say `ViewController A` is the class where you click on the camera button starting  `UIImagePickerController`.  `ViewController A`should be the delegate of `UIImagePickerController`.

Then, in `ViewController A` class, we define the function  which is called when you click on the button Use.

```
// This function is invoked when you click the button USE
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info 
{   
    // Go back to the view A
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    // Get Image
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    // Go to view B
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:showMapViewController animated:NO];
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't because if I push from `self.navigationController` only a tab display the image picker